# Laravel calls a different method than specified in Route function

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having troubles with something that I just can't explain. I'm working with Laravel and I just write a route for get method, no such a big deal, but for this route I'm calling a method called **generatefile** and Laravel is calling my **index** method which doesn't make sense. This is my code.

**ReportController**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\ReportTypes;
  use App\Report;
  use App\Hardware;
  use App\Customer;
  use App\User;
  use App\ReportNotes;
  use DB;
  use PDF;

  use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

  class ReportController extends Controller
   {
    public function index($type){

    $data = new ReportTypes;

    $datatype = $data->getData($type);

    $hm = $datatype->report_type_includes_hardware ? true : false;

    $customers = Customer::all();

    $users = User::all();

    $report = new Report;

    $reports = $report->getData($type);

    if($hm){

        $models = Hardware::all();

        return view('report/types/index',compact('datatype','hm','models','customers','users','reports'));

    }

    return view('report/types/index',compact('datatype','hm','reports','customers','users'));

    
}

public function generatefile(){

    $data = ['title' => 'Welcome to HDTuto.com'];

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', $data);

    return $pdf->download('hdtuto.pdf');

}

public function details($type, $folio){
    
    $data = new ReportTypes;

    $datatype = $data->getData($type);

    $report_notes = new ReportNotes;

    $type_id = DB::table('report_types')->where('report_type_serie','=',$type)->get()->first();

    $report = DB::table('reports')->where([
        ['FK_report_type_id','=',$type_id->PK_report_type_id],
        ['report_folio','=',$folio]
    ])->first();


    
    $notes = $report_notes->getData($report->PK_report_id);

    return view('report/types/details',compact('datatype','notes','report'));

}

public function store(Request $request){

    $report = new Report;
    $data = new ReportTypes;

    $report->FK_report_type_id = $request->RPType;
    $report->report_folio = $data->nextFolio($request->RPType);
    $report->FK_customer_id = $request->RPCustomer;
    $report->FK_hardware_model_id = $request->RPHardware;
    $report->FK_creator_user_id = $request->RPCreator;
    $report->FK_responsable_user_id = $request->RPResp;
    $report->FK_assistant1_user_id = $request->RPAssist;
    $report->FK_report_state_id = 1;
    $report->report_issue = $request->RPIssue;
    $report->report_description_issue = $request->RPDescIssue;
    $report->report_created_at = Carbon::now();
    $report->report_attended_at = Carbon::now();
    $report->report_updated_at = Carbon::now();
    $report->report_finished_at = Carbon::now();

    $report->save();

    $data->incrementFolio($request->RPType);

    return redirect()->route('reports',$request->RPTypeSerie);

   }
}
```

My Route

```
Route::get('reports/getfile','ReportController@getfile')->name('report.generatefile');
Route::get('reports/{type}','ReportController@index')->name('reports');
```

And when I try to access this route, I get this:

[image]

I get the error in the index method, but I'm not calling it.

Can anyone please explain me why is this happening?

Comment: what function do you want to use in the controller?

Comment: Can you add more of your routes file? It's possible that there's another one matching the same request being called first

Comment: Travis, you're right, there ir another route that matches, I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your route before to index route and try. 
You can to check this question: [Laravel Route issues with Route order in web.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942333/laravel-route-issues-with-route-order-in-web-php)

Answer (score 0):

**First**, check your `route.php` if there is no duplicate route URI w/ the same method `Route::get('reports/getfile'...`  or route name `->name('report.generatefile')`.

It is possible that you have 2 duplicate routes and you are using the route which uses `ReportController@index`.

**Second**, `getFile` function doesn't seem to exist in your `ReportController` which you are using in your route:

`Route::get('reports/getfile','ReportController@getfile')->name('report.generatefile');`

Comment: You're right, I correct that but still not working,Petter's answer resolve the problem

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
php artisan passport:install --force
```