# Laravel Routing Order Multiple "Homepages" Based On Auth

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel routing file (`web.php`) like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::get('/',  function () {
            return 'Hello World';
        });

});




Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

In my application the unauthenticated homepage must go to the login screen. When authenticated, the homepage changes. However, if I run this code and login - I get an infinite redirect because the `LoginController` has this line:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

So basically, even thought Laravel [should read the routes file top to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44944484/4942980), it seems this isn't applying in my case (maybe because of the `::group()`) or I am doing something wrong.

How can I accomplish a homepage that goes to the login form while also redirecting back to the same url (`/`) for authenticated users for a different authenticated view (and no redirect loop).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this inside a [guest](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php) middleware that checks for an authenticated user. For this case you'll want an authenticated guard check first:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Apply the `guest` middleware to the login endpoint:

```
Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')
->middleware('guest')
->name('login');
```

**Note:** Only apply the `guest` middleware to guest routes, otherwise you run the risk of redirect loops.

Comment: I tried this with the `guest` middleware but instead of redirect `/home` I would want to redirect `/` and thus it doesn't alleviate the redirect loop... maybe if I try a named route redirect instead...

Comment: And that doesn't work either... sigh... perhaps I just need a different route name/url :(

Answer (score -1):

Why not handle this in your view?

You can simply remove one of the route declaration from your web.php.
Then go ahead with conditional rendering.

```
@auth
 Show Home page
@endauth

@guest
Show Login
@endguest
```

I guess middleware does not prevent request from hitting the routes,
It rather prevents request from going through.

You can't use middle`enter code here`ware to decide with route to hit, thereby the loop.
When you're thinking in terms of bottom down processing, laravel has already registered every declared routes.

Comment: I prefer to not have the view handle such logic... but thank you for articulating this option.