# Routing Error - how to call same route with out any error

Tags: laravel

**First Route**

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'method'])->name('home.index');
```

**Second Route**

```
Route::get('/{slug}', [Controller::class, 'method'])->name('view');
```

**Third Route**

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [HomeController::class, 'method'])->name('home');
```

how to call route with out any error??

Comment: Just alter the route sequence and it will work. Let me know the results.

Comment: my prblm is running, now check my question i some changes in question

Comment: You can check my ans as below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Route issues with Route order in web.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942333/laravel-route-issues-with-route-order-in-web-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to order something like this,

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'method'])->name('home.index');
Route::get('/dashboard', [HomeController::class, 'method'])->name('home');
Route::get('/{slug}', [Controller::class, 'method'])->name('view');
```

Let me know the results.

Comment: this is not working...thank for the answer

Comment: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\frontend\Controller::View(), 1 passed in H:\xampp\htdocs\faithtyme\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

Comment: This should work. Can you please share the URL that you fired?

Comment: Also the signature of ```View()```.

Comment: http://localhost/myProject/

Comment: http://localhost/myProject/test

Comment: and you have error in first route or in second?

Comment: done complete work

Comment: your answer is write but my mistack in code

Comment: Thanks Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Just Change the order of routes

```php
    Route::get('/dashboard', [HomeController::class, 'method'])->name('home');
    Route::get('/{slug}', [Controller::class, 'method'])->name('view');
```