# Laravel route resolving to a different method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to set up a basic Laravel CRUD application, and I'm getting stuck setting up the pages for each action.

When I visit the route **case/create**, it opens the page for **show** instead.

**routes/web.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HospitalCase as HospitalCase;

Route::controller(HospitalCase::class)->group(function() {
    Route::get('/cases','index')->middleware('auth')->name('cases');
    Route::get('/case/{id}','show')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('/case/create','create')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('/case/create','store')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('/case/edit/{$id}','edit')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('/case/edit/{$id}','update')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('/case/delete/{$id}','destroy')->middleware('auth');
});
```

**HospitalCase.php controller**

```
class HospitalCase extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        echo 'index';
    }

    function create()
    {
        echo 'create';
    }

    function show($id)
    {
        echo 'show';
    }

    function store()
    {
        // validation rules
    }

    function edit($id)
    {
        return view('case/edit');
    }

    function update($id)
    {
    }

    function destroy($id)
    {
    }
}
```

**This is what I see on the browser:**

[image]

I have been trying to figure this out for hours and can't think of what I'm doing wrong.

PS: The auth middleware is using laravel breeze (unmodified)

Comment: Sorry, about that. Lost my touch after being away from programming for 3 years. I'll update the post.

Comment: No worries! Welcome back! Also, for your issue, try putting the wild-card route _after_ the static one. `case/create` is matching the wildcard `case/{id}`, or maybe use a Resource Controller: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Not a laravel person but I can see the collision. Simple fix would be '/case/view/{id}' - assume it sees string `create` as `id`. Quick search suggests: `->where('id', '[0-9]+');`

Comment: ^ That goes against Laravel route conventions. You're correct about the cause @ficuscr, but the solution is to actually move `Route::get('/case/{id}','show')->middleware('auth');` below `Route::post('/case/create','store')->middleware('auth');`; wildcard routes go _after_ static/hard-coded ones.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis, `case/create` was matching the wildcard `case/{id}`. I'll also look into Resource controllers.

Comment: Haha yup  Sidenote, I voted to close this. While it's a little convoluted, it has been asked and answered on SO before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942333/laravel-route-issues-with-route-order-in-web-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to reiterate what @TimLewis has suggested, I think you need to put this route:

```php
Route::get('/case/create','create')->middleware('auth');
```

Above this route:

```php
Route::get('/case/{id}','show')->middleware('auth');
```

But you could try using Laravel’s route resource so you don’t need to write out all the routes -

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\HospitalCaseController;

Route::resource('case', HospitalCaseController::class);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's showing the show route is because you defined

```
Route::get('/case/{id}','show')->middleware('auth');
```

before it, therefore, it's matching `case/create` as `show('create')`

Try defining the route afterwards.

```
Route::get('/case/create','create')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/case/create','store')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/case/{id}','show')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Please remember to try and find existing questions/answers with the same issue before posting an answer. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942333/laravel-route-issues-with-route-order-in-web-php, amongst others. Not going to downvote/recommend deletion or anything, but just a reminder for general housekeeping.