# Laravel API return HTML GET Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, vuejs3, vue-router, laravel-api

I'm trying to do it:

```
Route::get('/foo', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json('Ready');
});
```

I get an answer HTML :(

But POST is works:

```
Route::post('/bar', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json('Ready');
});
```

result: "Ready"

What could be the problem?
Thx.

EDIT:
ok. I use Vue 3 and Vue-router, so i changed the file web.php:

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
return view('index'); })->where('any', '.*');
```

(to work SPA)

Then I changed to

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('index'); 
})
```

Now the GET request works!

But Vue-router can't work properly without this code.

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () { return view('index'); })->where('any', '.*');
```

What should I do ? Thanks.

Comment: Read the content of the HTML answer - it can be the output of an Exception. You can just look at `/foo` in the browser. Does it display anything?

Comment: Html answer - full index page

Comment: Did you added a Content-Type = application/json  on you header request?

Comment: @Nelson Mutane
Yes I am using Postman to test my requests and I have added this header request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Route issues with Route order in web.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942333/laravel-route-issues-with-route-order-in-web-php)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using web.php instead of api.php routing file.
By default all closure routes from web.php are parsed to Renderable object, which renders the output to a HTML.
If you do use api.php the closure routes will be parsed to a JsonResponse.

In summary, please do use the api.php for json responses and web.php or views only responses (aka. renderables).

Finally your vue-router parser from laravel router should be set at the end of the file.

You have

```php
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('index'); })->where('any', '.*');
});
```

I strongly recommend:

```php
// All of your other routes here...

Route::view("/{any?}", "index")->where("any", ".*");
```